# GeoDataManager putPoint method causing exception

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am attempting to use the Geo Library in an application I am building. I follow the  steps detailed in this tutorial for creating a table and inserting a geopoint into the table. However, when I get to this line

```
PutPointResult putPointResult = geoDataManager.putPoint(putPointRequest);
```

I get an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/geometry/S2LatLng
at com.amazonaws.geo.s2.internal.S2Manager.generateGeohash(S2Manager.java:116)
at com.amazonaws.geo.dynamodb.internal.DynamoDBManager.putPoint(DynamoDBManager.java:123)
at com.amazonaws.geo.GeoDataManager.putPoint(GeoDataManager.java:131)
at geolibraryTest.GeoLibraryTest.main(GeoLibraryTest.java:72)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.geometry.S2LatLng
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 4 more
```

Can anyone help me understand why I might be getting this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the [DynamoDB GEO](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-geo) doesn't put the s2-geometry jar in the classpath.

Are you using maven? or have you build the classpath on your own?

Comment: I build the classpath on my own. I added the s2-geometry jar to the class path, but now I am getting this exception

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Preconditions

Comment: it's not a good idea to build classpaths on your own. you should use maven/ivy to manage the dependencies. The class you are now missing is from Google Guava: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/Release18